# Iterator in swift is skipping elements?

Tags: arrays, swift, iterator

I am using iterators to cycle through an array of flash cards, but the iterator is going every other, for example, I tested it by entering in numbers 1-7 as new cards (in order) but when I flip through the deck it only displays 2, then 4, then 6, then back to 2. When I print out the deckIterator in the functions it gives a corresponding integer back, so for card 2 the iterator prints 2. I'm not sure If i'm using the iterator correct, could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchData()
}

func fetchData() {
    deckArray.removeAll()
    deckIterator = nil
    do {
        fetched = try context.fetch(Card.fetchRequest())
        for each in fetched {
            let term = each.term
            let definition = each.definition
            termLabel.text = each.term!
            definitionLabel.text = each.definition!
            let Card = card(term: term!, definition: definition!)
            deckArray.append(Card)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    deckIterator = deckArray.makeIterator()
}

@IBAction func leftSwipe(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    getNextCardPlease()
    self.definitionLabel.isHidden = true
    alreadyFlipped = false
}

func getNextCardPlease(){
    if(deckIterator?.next() == nil){
        fetchData()
    } else {
        let next = deckIterator?.next()
        termLabel.text = next?.term
        definitionLabel.text = next?.definition
    }
}
```

Comment: You asked a question and it was correctly answered. You should accept an answer and close this out.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `next()`, we iterate. So every call to `getNextCardPlease` iterates twice. Count them:

```
if(deckIterator?.next() == nil){ // 1
    fetchData()
} else {
    let next = deckIterator?.next() // 2
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't have a great understanding of iterators in swift but just from experience with other languages I didn't think if(deckIterator?.next) would cause it to iterate

Comment: If you call a method, the method does what it does, regardless of whether you capture the result or not. And that's true in _every_ computer language, probably.

Comment: right right, I was thinking in terms of linked lists for some reason

Answer (score 0):

The problems was once `if(deckIterator?.next() == nil)` gets called, the iterator iterates. Iterators do not work like linked lists.